# How to import an eclipse android project that has libraries dependencies in android studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How can one import eclipse android project that has some libraries dependencies in android studio?

I tried using automatic import in android studio however there were lots of errors so I would like to import eclipse android project in android studio .
Any suggestion would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these following steps:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

Answer (score 0):

### Step1:

Open your project in eclipse,Right click on the project in the project explorer and click on Export

---

[image]

---

### Step 2:

In the next dialog box, click on Genreate Gradle build files and then click on YES

---

[image]

---

Now import your project in Android Studio and start Working on it....